# Show that if $x_{n}$ converges to $x_0$ , then $Ax_0 = y$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convergence-divergence

Let $A$ be a square matrix of size $N$, which we assume to be invertible. We define the following sequence:

$$x_{n + 1} = x_{n} - A^{T}(Ax_{n} - y), $$

and $x_{0}$ is given.

Show that if $x_{n} \rightarrow x_{0}$, then $Ax = y$.

---

I have been stuck on this problem for a while, and I don't really know how to proceed. I thought about using the definition of convergence with $\epsilon-N$, but I haven't gotten anywhere with that.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is $x$ and $x_0$ supposed to be the same?

Comment: The final identity should be $Ax_0=y$.

Comment: Yes they are the same.

Comment: Still not fixed, but using the notation $x_0$ for the limit is not a good idea as there is a confusion with $n=0$. Use $x$ or $x_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking limits you get $x_0=x_0-A^{T}(Ax_0-y)$. Hence $A^{T}(Ax_0-y)=0$. Since $A$ is invertible so is $A^{T}$. Hence $Ax_0-y=0$ or $Ax_0=y$.

Answer (score 1):

From the given recurrence,

$$Ax_n-y=A^{-T}(x_{n+1}-x_n).$$

Convergence of $x_n$ implies $\exists\,n$

$$\|Ax_n-y\|<\|A^{-T}\|\epsilon$$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If you know that $x_n \to \boldsymbol{\ell}$ say (where $\boldsymbol{\ell}$ is a vector here), then you can send $n$ to infinity on both sides and use limit laws, as well as the fact that matrix multiplication is continuous (i.e. if $x_n\to \boldsymbol{\ell}$, then $Ax_n\to A\boldsymbol{\ell}$; make sure you know why this is true!).